# WordPress не видит подключение стилей

Tags: wordpress

Есть файл `index.php` со всей разметкой, далее создал файл `functions.php`

Там разместил такой код

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_styles' );

function theme_name_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/styles.min.css');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
```

Но по какой-то причине WordPress прописывает не правильный путь.

А данную строку вообще игнорирует. Хотя главный файл со стилями 100% есть

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'main-styles', get_stylesheet_uri() );
```

По какой-то причине, пропускается слеш
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но в функции он проставлен

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Скачайте пустую тему на underscoze, там всё есть, уже давно ни кто не создаёт шаблон пустой темы) все пользуются готовым набором пустых файлов)